# Emulating Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable Image with QEMU

Tags: qemu, arm64

I am learning how to use QEMU and have been trying to boot a Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable image using QEMU on a Kali Linux machine but to no avail. The image I am trying to boot as a simple firmware and from what I gathered online, the command I used was this:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu cortex-a53 -kernel image.img -append "console=ttyAMA0".
```

Once I run this, the QEMU monitor pops up but nothing is booting. Do forgive me if this is a super basic question, I am trying to learn a new thing here. Thanks for any input!